# Android - Brain Cramping

Tags: android

Alright, I have a simple boolean at the top of this class, standing.  In the thread, I have the following code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if(standing == true){
            player.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            standing = false;}
        if(standing == false){
            playerC.handleActionDown((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            standing = true;}

        //check if in the lower part of the screen we exit
        if(event.getY() > getHeight() -50 && event.getX() > getWidth() -50) {
            thread.setRunning(false);
            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Coords: x=" + event.getX() + ",y=" + event.getY());
        }
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        //touch was released

    }
    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg1),0, 0, null);
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
  if(standing == true){
        player.draw(canvas);
   } 
    if(standing == false){
        playerC.draw(canvas);
   }


}
```

Why won't it switch the dawing back to standing, that's all I want.  Click it once and it goes to crouching, click it again and it stands.  I know this is stupid simple, but I can't get it right for some reason.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you reformat please?  some code is in code blocks, some is not, it's quite hard to read

Comment: I'd suggest that you rename your question so that it feels more at home on Stackoverflow than on some site dedicated to brain anatomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to read the unformatted code I see; If standing is true, you set it to false. then you test if standing is false, which sets it back to true.  It should be `else if`, not `if`.